# C++/CLI System.Timers.Timer elapsed 20 in seconds while set Interval to 100ms

Tags: c#, c++, timer

I use a timer `System::Timers::Timer` in a C++/CLI code, want to elapse every 100ms. But it trigger in 20 seconds. But I write a same code in C#, it works well.

C++ code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Timers;
using namespace System::Threading;

static void SysTick(Object^ state, ElapsedEventArgs^ e)
{
    DateTime _current = System::DateTime::Now;
    String^ dt_str = String::Format("NOW: @{0}.{1:000}", _current.ToLongTimeString(), _current.Millisecond);
    Console::WriteLine(dt_str);
}

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    System::Timers::Timer^ sys_tick = gcnew System::Timers::Timer(100);
    sys_tick->BeginInit();
    sys_tick->AutoReset = true;
    sys_tick->Elapsed += gcnew ElapsedEventHandler(SysTick);
    sys_tick->EndInit();

    sys_tick->Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Console::WriteLine("[{0}] Main thread sleep 1000 ms", i);
        Thread::Sleep(1000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;

namespace CSharpTimer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void SysTick(object state, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("NOW: {0}.{1:000}", now.ToLongTimeString(), now.Millisecond);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(100);
            timer.BeginInit();
            timer.AutoReset = true;
            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(SysTick);
            timer.EndInit();

            timer.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Main thread sleep 1000 ms", i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

C++ output:

```
[0] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
NOW: @5:59:58 PM.284
[1] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[2] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[3] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[4] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[5] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[6] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[7] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[8] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[9] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[10] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[11] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[12] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[13] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[14] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[15] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[16] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[17] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[18] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[19] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[20] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
NOW: @6:00:18 PM.421
[21] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
[22] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
```

C# output:

```
[0] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
NOW: 6:01:23 PM.032
NOW: 6:01:23 PM.134
NOW: 6:01:23 PM.242
NOW: 6:01:23 PM.352
NOW: 6:01:23 PM.460
NOW: 6:01:23 PM.575
NOW: 6:01:23 PM.682
NOW: 6:01:23 PM.790
NOW: 6:01:23 PM.899
[1] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
NOW: 6:01:24 PM.007
NOW: 6:01:24 PM.122
NOW: 6:01:24 PM.231
NOW: 6:01:24 PM.339
NOW: 6:01:24 PM.447
NOW: 6:01:24 PM.554
NOW: 6:01:24 PM.663
NOW: 6:01:24 PM.780
NOW: 6:01:24 PM.888
[2] Main thread sleep 1000 ms
NOW: 6:01:24 PM.995
NOW: 6:01:25 PM.104
NOW: 6:01:25 PM.212
NOW: 6:01:25 PM.320
```

Comment: It works as expected...

Comment: My friend and I are both in this situation. Which version of .NET framework do you use?

Comment: .net 4.5 but I also can't see any reason it shouldn't work like that.

Comment: Did you try creating and starting the timer in C++ on a different thread then the main thread ?

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti It worked for me, too. .NET 4.5 in VS2013. I wonder which MSVC runtime versions show the problem.

Comment: I use VS2012. I have tried to start the timer in another thread, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was me who encountered this problem. My friend *Filly Hsu* asked this question here.
The downvoting costed my friends two points without any solution about the strange problem.

I asked the same question on MSDN and several hours later a member gave me a [solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9ea73719-ef15-4c09-a5cf-885b5b37b3f2/why-ccli-systemtimerstimer-triggered-callback-every-20-seconds-while-set-interval-to-100ms?forum=clr):

> put a `Debug::Write("")` after `Console::Write()`

And now the it's solved, though I still don't know why.

Comment: It looks like there was only one down-vote, so no worries. I'm assuming you ran the code in Debug mode, because otherwise Debug::Write would be ignored. Did you see a similar problem when compiling in a Release configuration?

Comment: @AustinMullins : Compiling in release mode and hitting F5 to run the program, the same problem would happen again. But when you press ctrl-f5 or run the execution file independly, it just works fine. I think there must be something wrong with VS.

Comment: @FillyHsu In release mode, the debug module absolutely won't work, so that the bug will appear again. But in release mode you don't really need debugging, do you?

Comment: Which version of VS? This has to be caused by some kind of debugger setting (or bug, irony abounds).

Comment: @AustinMullins  VS 2013 on Windows 8.1, compiling with .Net Framework 4.0. I'm not on my develop machine and I cannot give you the exactly settings to find which option was set wrong. I just used a standard CLR program with C++. All codes are in the question.